# Why the debugger is inconsistent in showing @State properties?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the picture below I see the following inconsistencies:

1. The string "(username)" is printed as expected by the program but the debugger throws an error: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
   FWSNewsReader.LoginView2.username.getter : Swift.String
2. The automatically synthesized _username property is shown in the view variable windows of the debug as having an undocumented internal "value" property but the wrappedValue public property is not shown. Why is that?
3. assigning a new value to the state variable with `e _username.wrappedValue = "newVal"` is possible ( although correctly throwing a warning *Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior*) but trying to do the same with `e username = "newVal"` throws an error : *Couldn't lookup symbols:
   FWSNewsReader.LoginView2.username.setter : Swift.String*

the code:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                VStack(spacing: 10){
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                        .padding(10).background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    TextField("Password", text: $password)
                        .padding(10).background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 500)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don’t use screenshots.

Comment: Please don't use `return` inside the `body` of a view. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view).

Comment: You can observe changes to state by using the `.onChange` modifier. I usually add breakpoints inside the `onChange` block or any modifier that takes a closure. I don't think breakpoint in the view body are useful since the computed property can run based on internal conditions. You can also add a `_ = Self._printChanges()` somewhere inside `body` to know what state caused the view to re-render.

Comment: @koen IMO a screenshot is pretty appropriate in this case, to communicate the state of the breakpoint, debugger variables and view all at the same time. Adding the code as code would also be nice, though.

Comment: I don't think anybody here can answer this, this is part of the "magic" of SwiftUi wrappers

Comment: @alobaili Please comment on my actual concerns, not about some other possibilities that are off topic

Comment: I will try to clarify more. Regarding number 1, Placing a breakpoint inside `body` is not reliable way for debugging and have shown inconsistent behavior across Swift and SwiftUI versions. Regarding number 2, asking how internal and undocumented behavior works will most likely not result in a good answer, even if there was a publicly known answer, it is not guaranteed to being the correct answer in the future. Regarding number 3, it is the same as my answer for number 1. To close my comment with some actionable info, I provided alternative ways for you to debug the state variables in the code.